# How to display a block in the webform confirmation page?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm looking for a way to display a block (a view) in the page that is displayed when a webform is submitted.
This is the url of the confirmation/done page :

```
domain.com/node/*/done
```

I can't figure out a way to target this url structure by using the ***Show block on specific pages*** or ***context path*** settings.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Well i'm pretty sure i tried it and it didn't work but now .. it works. So i'm guessing i didn't set something up correctly during the test.

Answer (score 0):

It is funny how you have a part of answer in your question. Since you have a block, in **"Show block on specific pages"**, check **"Only on the listed pages"** and type-in `node/*/done` (more on [wildcards](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiYtZOGjt7UAhVRET4KHbQLA5E4ChAWCDEwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdrupal.techjaffa.xyz%2Fshow-a-block-on-a-certain-url-with-wildcard%2F&usg=AFQjCNEufjYMBHT7-RYVNtT9ZtSUMN-L5Q))

Get back if I missed something here.

Comment: Funny indeed, i tried again and it works using the "show block on specific pages" setting. I guess i did something wrong the first time. I'm still unable to do it using context though